# keep track of time as user changes web pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a requirement where a user presses a start timer button and it begins keeping track of time. As the user moves through the website, I want the time to continue tracking, until they press the stop button.

Obviously, this cannot be achieved through client-side javascript alone, since for each page refresh time will be lost. One solution I thought was to use faye/websockets to just push the time to the browser, but for every second that lapses, that will push data to client - a strain on the server.

The only solution I can come up with is keep track of the time in javascript and then capture the page unload event send, ajax request to server with the amount of time, and let the server continue incrementing time until the next page is fully loaded. This means it will not be using push technology, just regular ajax. Is this the optimal option here or is there a better solution?

Comment: In this case I think the Ajax solution will work just fine, what are your concerns?

Comment: I don't know ruby-on-rails. If you can use the session, that will be great. When user press start button, set the session variable with Start Date and Time. When user press the stop button subtract current date&time from Start Date&Time; and you will get the total time. Session is stored based on user, you'll be fine. Again, I don't know Ruby on Rail, but If it supports session then you can use rit.

Comment: Maybe you could explain the purpose of the timer. Does the user pay for every second it uses the website? Should the server be aware of the elapsed time?

Comment: The timer is used to record how long a specific task takes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the case where the user kills the browser? You won't be able to capture the unload event in this case.

If you want a client side solution, try putting the start time in the localStorage where this will persist across page loads. Then when the user hits stop, you can make an ajax call to the server with the elapsed time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to display a timer to the user, which updates every second.

I have built a web application like that. It was a single-page application (AngularJS), so the user could navigate from 'page' to 'page' without a complete web page being loaded and the timer kept running. Would that be an option in your case?

Otherwise, you could put the start time in a cookie and every second display the difference between the current time and the start time.

A few other options, which are less preferred:

1. Run the web site in an iframe and keep the timer outside the iframe.
2. Let the timer run on the server and make a small AJAX request to the server every second (yes, I know...).
3. Hybrid: Let the timer run on the server and on the client and synchronize the client with the server on every page load.

Options 2 and 3 require a stateful server (with all its drawbacks).